# Regex: Pattern to find Java class in .java file

Tags: java, regex

I want to find a class' name when reading through a .java file. I'm returning no match right now using this regular expression:

```
\\s*[public][private]\\s*class\\s*(\\w*)\\s*\\{
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;


public class HW4Solution {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        //Prompt user for path to file.
        File file = null;
        Scanner pathScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (file == null || !file.exists())
        {
            System.out.print("Enter valid file path: ");
            file = new File(pathScan.next());
        }
        pathScan.close();
        System.out.println("File: " + file.getPath() + " found.");

        //Read file line by line into buffered reader
        StringBuffer componentString = new StringBuffer(100);
        String currentLine;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getPath()));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //TODO: Find class declarations
        //TODO: Find superclasses
        //TODO: Find instance variable declarations
        //TODO: Find method signatures
        //TODO: Find access modifier
        //TODO: Find return type
        //TODO: Find method name

        //Creating patterns to look for!
        //Class declarations
        Pattern classDeclarationPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*[public][private]\\s*class\\s*(\\w*)\\s*\\{");
        try {
            while((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                Matcher classDeclarationMatcher = classDeclarationPattern.matcher(currentLine);
                if(classDeclarationMatcher.group(1) != null){
                    componentString.append("Found class declaration: " + classDeclarationMatcher.group(3) + "\n");
                    /*if(classDeclarationMatcher.group(5) != null){
                        componentString.append("\tsuperclass: " + classDeclarationMatcher.group(5) + "\n");
                    }*/
                    System.out.println(classDeclarationMatcher.group());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try{
                if (bufferedReader !=null) {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println(componentString.toString());

    }
}
```

I eventually want to be able to determine if a class declaration has a superclass and get that too but for now I'm having enough trouble (which I shouldn't) getting the name of the class.

Comment: you never call `find()` on the matcher. That means you are not looking for results.

Comment: @iTech huh? `[class]` is definitely not what he is looking for

Comment: @kmaz13 you realize this is essentially a heuristic method and will have false positives (and probably false negatives also)?

Comment: @MiserableVariable string-quoted class headers are such false positives, and generic classes would need to be covered as well.

Comment: If you need this to work reliably, you'd be more likely to succeed by parsing the source using the [Eclipse JDT API](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/package-summary.html), for example ([regular expressions? now you have two problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html), etc)

Comment: The question and both answers so far assume the class declaration is contained in one line. Although I personally code that way, it's not a requirement at all.

Comment: @JanDvorak your comment should have been directed to OP, I am well aware of pitfalls of using regexp for parsing :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`[public]` is not matching what you think it should. It is a character class, which matches either of those characters in `public`. You should use `pipe` to match alternate words.

You can use following regex, extended to consider `super` classes or interface: -

```
Pattern.compile("\\s*(public|private)\\s+class\\s+(\\w+)\\s+((extends\\s+\\w+)|(implements\\s+\\w+( ,\\w+)*))?\\s*\\{");
```

Note that, you should use `\\s+` with `+` quantifier when matching space between `public|private` and the `class` keyword. Because you expect at least `1` space there. `\\s*` will match `0` space, which is not correct, since `publicclass` is not valid.

Apart from that, there can be some more options to consider here. Like `static inner classes`, or `generic classes`, that will require minor modification in there, which you can do on your own. I've just given a little insight on to how to approach.

---

Also, one more important thing. Before you can get the result from your group, you should call `Matcher#find()` method to do the actual matching.

Answer (score 1):

RegExp for class declaration:

```
private String classRegExp = "(((|public|final|abstract|private|static|protected)(\\s+))?(class)(\\s+)(\\w+)(<.*>)?(\\s+extends\\s+\\w+)?(<.*>)?(\\s+implements\\s+)?(.*)?(<.*>)?(\\s*))\\{$";
```

for interface declaration:

```
private String interfaceRegExp = "(((|public|final|abstract|private|static|protected)(\\s+))?interface(\\s+)(\\w+)(<.*>)?(\\s+extends\\s+\\w+)?(<.*>)?(\\s+implements\\s+)?(.*)?(<.*>)?(\\s*))\\{$";
```

for enum declaration :

```
private String enumRegExp = "((((public|final|private|static|protected)(\\s+))?enum(\\s+)(\\w+)?(\\s+implements\\s+\\w+)?(.*)?\\s*))\\{$";
```